# SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 Authentication credentials invalid

Tags: cakephp, smtp

I am using jango smtp setting in my project.

Below is my code:

```
funcation sendmail()
{

$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(

  'timeout' => '30',

  'port' => '25', 

  'host' => 'relay.jangosmtp.net',

  'username' => 'xxxx',

  'password' => '1234567'

);
}
```

sendmail function gives the following error:

```
SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 Authentication credentials invalid
```

What may be the reason?

Comment: what jango documentation are you using? can you link us?

Comment: Hay sorry it worked, problem was,invalid credentials..!!I changed to correct one and it worked fine for me.. thanks..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***This is basically because credentials is not correct !!***

May be this will help you !!

```
535 Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process.
```

If a SMTP client authenticates but the username or password is incorrect, or the account is disabled, hMailServer sends this error message to the client.

http://support.qualityunit.com/156325-Email-is-not-sent-because-of-failed-authentication

```
SMTP error 535 authentication failed in roundcube

SMTP Error (435): Authentication failed
```

If you face SMTP error 535 Authentication Failed while sending an email from round cube, then you can check the following things.

```
[root@server1 ~]# vi /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/roundcube/config/main.inc.php
```

and changed

```
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = ‘%u’;
to
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = ”;
```